# SQLAlchemy - how to slice arrays to get the full range? [:] is compiled to [NULL:NULL]

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm stuck at a specific problem with SQLAlchemy. Basically, I have a table with a column that is a nested array (`{{filename1, file_url1}, {filename2, file_url2}}`).

I've managed to write a filter query to that searches in the first element of all arrays (so in this case, by filename) using an `ILIKE` operator.

Yet, I have a problem with proper querying ALL of the arrays, as the `[:]` slicing operator produces a `[NULL:NULL]` slice in the compiled query, while I need a simple `[:]` as this is something that is supported by PostgreSQL.

The query in SQLAlchemy looks like this

```py
cast(DataStorage.result_files[:][1], sql_string).ilike(f"%{request.args.get('result_files', '')}%")
```

But produces `CAST(data_storage.result_files[NULL:NULL][%(param_1)s] AS VARCHAR) ILIKE %(param_2)s`, instead of `CAST(data_storage.result_files[:][%(param_1)s] AS VARCHAR) ILIKE %(param_2)s`

When the `result_files[:][1]`'s first slice is set to a specific slice range, it works perfectly, but I have a problem with `[:]`. Is there a simple solution for passing `[:]` as is when the query is compiled?

Comment: For the benefit of any other Python programmers confused by the syntax, apparently `[:][1]` is actually how PostgreSQL slicing syntax works, and *not* the buggy thing it would be if applied to a Python list, NumPy array, or other familiar Python collection object. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING